# web-audio api does not work after first beep

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I am building a simple extendable metronome class using JavaScript, inspired by code found in "A Tale of Two Clocks" here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/scheduling/.

I have converted the original code to a class, following the same basic pattern as the original, and I've included some additional bits and pieces. The code works perfectly, except for one huge problem, which is that the oscillator does not fire (in my version of the code) after the first sound is played. If I include an alert in "scheduleNote", the sound works perfectly.

```
this.scheduleNote = function( beatNumber ) {

    if (( this.noteResolution == 1 ) && ( beatNumber % 2 )) {
        return; // we're not playing non-8th 16th notes
    }
    if (( this.noteResolution == 2 ) && ( beatNumber % 4 )) {
        return; // we're not playing non-quarter 8th notes
    }

    var oscillator = myAC.audioContext.createOscillator(); // Create sound source
    var gainNode = myAC.audioContext.createGain(); // Create gain node

    oscillator.type = "square"; // Square wave
    oscillator.frequency.value = this.frequency; // Frequency in hertz 
    oscillator.connect(gainNode); // Connect sound source 2 to gain node 2
    gainNode.connect(myAC.audioContext.destination); // Connect gain node 2 to output
    gainNode.gain.value = 1; // Set volume to 100 percent
    oscillator.start(myAC.audioContext.currentTime);
    oscillator.stop(myAC.audioContext.currentTime + this.noteLength);
// alert("un-comment this: suddenly the sound works perfectly...");
    oscillator = null;
} // this.scheduleNote( beatNumber )
```

My questions: why does my sound not play (on the second++ loop), and most importantly, what is the fix?

My example: http://codepen.io/robwelan/pen/LGRJdE.

Comment: There seems to be an infinite loop somewhere. I don't have the time to debug right now, but I'm getting "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" in the console, which makes me think that is the case...

Comment: @OskarEriksson I'm not near a computer for a few days. scheduleNote (as I recall) is designed to run endlessly (the play/pause button controls it firing).